# Application of Gronwall inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f=f(x,t)$ and $g=g(x,t)$ be two periodic continuous functions on $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^{*}_+$ such that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2\le \|g\|_{L^2([0,1])}\|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}$$

Using Gronwall inequalities, how to show that

$$\|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2\le \|f(x,0)\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2e^{\|g\|^2_{L^2([0,1])}t}$$
for all $t>0$?

When I write $\|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}$, I mean $\|f(\cdot, t)\|_{L^1([0,1])}$ (which depends on $t$)

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a couple of squares in the right side, or your bound is not correct. Also, that there is no integral in the exponent of the bound appears suspicious. One could replace that with the maximum over the period, but that needs to be indicated.